# How can I add glow or a shadow to text in PHP's GD library?

Tags: php, gd

Is it possible to add glow or a shadow to text in GD? Currently I am using the imagettftext function.

Comment: These are *extremely* contrived questions, begging to be flagged as spam. You really should have at *least* kept this to a single question, especially since you've largely copy-pasted the same answer for both.

Comment: @meagar - I literally typed the title of this question into Google a few hours ago.  I'd recommend you do the same and take note of the *multiple* forum posts asking the same question [and going unanswered]

Comment: In particular, Andrew; the fact that you have come up with questions to which the answer is a link to your Github project can be a bit of a problem.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I ran into this problem and created a new function called `imagettftextblur` which I've released as open source at https://github.com/andrewgjohnson/imagettftextblur

Here is how to add a shadow:

```
imagettftextblur($image,$size,0,$x + 3,$y + 3,$shadow_color,$font,$string,1); // 1 can be higher to increase blurriness of the shadow
imagettftextblur($image,$size,0,$x,$y,$text_color,$font,$string);
```

Comment: I wish there were bonus points which could be given for not only answering, but sharing a solution through open source (as opposed to simply linking to someone else's work).

Comment: is this answer..?? problem solved..?

Comment: @DipeshParmar It is perfectly fine for people to ask and answer their own question, provided the question and answer follow our quality guidelines. That said, I don't know if the question here qualifies.

Comment: however quality of both question ans answer should be remain same even if it is self answered

Comment: It takes so much processing time. is there a way to make it lighter ?