# text-shadow/box-shadow equivalent in php gd

Tags: php, css, image-processing, gd

I am applying shadow effect on images using `box-shadow` property and on text using `text-shadow` property of CSS.

Is there any script or function available in GD that perform the same operation on text and images.

for example

```
<div style="text-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #FF0000;">Some Shadow Text</div>

  // how can i create image with shadow in php GD
```

Comment: Maybe check out [this SO Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15514985/570812)? Edit: maybe [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8289297/570812) too.

Comment: No GD cannot do anything that you've asked. You can emulate through some fancy script, but i wont recommended (I'm pretty sure that will hit your server like a truck, although you can "cache" the result for future uses). So, back to the question, [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/) is what you need ... or (I haven't used this) check out [Cairo](http://cairographics.org/) (seems to be pretty capable at doing weird image/vector manipulation)